# Alignment of property-values in CSS

Tags: css

I have a code similar to this:

```
        <p><strong>Name: </strong>Vicky</p>
        <p><strong>Surname: </strong>ONeill</p>
        <p><strong>Age: </strong></p>
```

I would like it to be shown like:

```
    Name: Vicky
 Surname: ONeill
     Age: 24
```

So it looks more "elegant" and ordered. Is there a way to do this in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strong {
  display:inline-block;
  min-width:12em;
  text-align:right;
}
```

However, this markup isn't really meant for this kind of data - a list of key/value pairs is hardly a 'paragraph'. Consider switching to a data list (`<dl>`, [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/kc6wqhct/)), its structure is inherently easier to layout like this in CSS.

Comment: That's great and totally right! I have a problem now with the DL style that I have updated

Comment: I have reverted the edit to the question since it would make it mismatch the answers. Just ask a new question if you have a new question  :)

Answer (score 1):

## The humble table element

The poor `<table>` has been unfairly stigmatised due to misuse. Your example is the perfect use for a `<table>` and here is an example including the [scope attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th#attr-scope) for the table headers:

[image: Screenshot]

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;  
}
th {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: normal;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Name:</th>
    <td>Vicky</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Surname:</th>
    <td>ONeill</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Age:</th>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

#### The description list option

If you must go for the `<dl>` option, give the parent a width and the child elements `width: 50%`. `box-sizing: border-box` calculates the padding with the width. Instead of `<hr>` use a bottom border.

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
dl {
  width: 200px;
}
dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
dd {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Name:</dt>
  <dd>Vicky</dd>
  <dt>Surname:</dt>
  <dd>ONeill</dd>
  <dt>Age:</dt>
  <dd>24</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see this can be solved with a table (and this is one of my complaints about the complex CSS, which I find difficult and not intuitive at all), but I find my data more appropriate for a DL. If I cant make DL work, I will go for your suggestion

Comment: @user1156544 - I added a solution using the `<dl>` as well, if you really want to use it :) I would use the table, it makes sense with the data being displayed and it's easier to create the look you want.

Comment: While I have to agree that tables are often unnecessarily shunned - I have seen people refuse to use tables for obviously tabular data because 'tables are evil' - it's not the best fitting semantical element here. The `<dl>` element is [specifically intended for](http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/) *"...an association list consisting of zero or more name-value groups (a description list). Each group must consist of one or more names (dt elements) followed by one or more values (dd elements). Within a single dl element, there should not be more than one dt element for each name."*

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes - I can't disagree with that :) I'm mostly referring to how easy it is to create the desired appearance for this particular example. The `<table>` option doesn't require any widths so it is much more flexible as it can expand naturally with its contents. There may be a slight compromise semantically compared with a `<dl>`, but it is a minor one.